# CordovaDatePicker Plugin not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i am using cordovadatepicker plugin, i am facing the issue when i click for selecting the date the datepicker dialog box is not opening.

i am getting the error:

```
"TypeError: Object 9/17/2015/10/16 has no method 'getMonth'
at DatePicker.show (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-datepicker/www/android/DatePicker.js:30:32)
at Object.show (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js:7:16910)
at Scope.$scope.ShowDate (file:///android_asset/www/dist/dist_js/app/controllers.js:1863:43)
at $parseFunctionCall (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20270:18)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:52468:9
at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22326:28)
at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22425:23)
at HTMLLabelElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:52467:13)
at HTMLLabelElement.eventHandler (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10939:21)
at triggerMouseEvent (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2856:7)"
```

here is my code:

in view:

```
 <label class="item item-input">

                  <input type="text" name="SheetDate" placeholder="Select Date"  value="{{TimeSheetDate.SelectDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy' }}"
                   datetime="yyyy-MM-dd" required readonly>
                   <i class="icon ion-android-calendar placeholder-icon" ng-click="ShowDate()"></i>
                </label>
```

in controller:

```
   var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date', // or 'time'
    allowOldDates: true,
    allowFutureDates: false,
    doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
    doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
    cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
    cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
  };
        $scope.ShowDate = function () {
            try {

               $q.when($cordovaDatePicker.show(options)).then(function (date) {
                    // alert(date);
                    TimeSheetDate.SelectDate=date;
                    fetchedDetail(TimeSheetDate.SelectDate);
                });
            }
            catch (e){
console.log(e);
            }
        };
```

My index file scripts:

```
  <!-- build:js dist_js/modules.js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-slugify/dist/angular-slugify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/collide/collide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-contrib-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/waves/dist/waves.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <script src="lib/ngStorage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- build:js dist_js/app.js -->
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/filters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/factories.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/templates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dist/dist_js/app/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

I am not getting where i did wrong. help me into this.

Comment: please change `value="{{TimeSheetDate.SelectDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy' }}"` to `ng-model="{{TimeSheetDate.SelectDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy' }}"` first.

Comment: please tell me can we formate the ng-model?

Comment: no i don't think so, why do not you format that in controller.